# Pytest - mocking a side_effect on mock's nested attribute function / method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a fixture mocking an external library like so, using pytest-mock, which is a wrapper around unittest.mock.

```py
# client.py

import Test as TestLibrary

class LibraryName():
   def get_client():
      return TestLibrary.Library()

# library_service.py

def using_library():
   '''
   Edited note: Library().attribute behind the scenes is set to
   self.attribute = Attribute() 
   so this may be affecting the mocking
   '''
   client = LibraryName.get_client()
   return client.attribute.method()

# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def library_client_mock(mocker):
    import Test as TestLibrary

    return mocker.patch.object(TestLibrary, 'Library')

# test_library_service.py

def test_library_method(library_client_mock):
   result = using_library()
```

I can mock a return value like so:

```
def test_library_method(library_client_mock):
   library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.return_value = "test"
   result = using_library()
   assert result == "test"
```

but I can't mock throwing an Exception with side_effect

```
def test_library_method(library_client_mock):
    library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.side_effect = TypeError # doesn't work
    library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.side_effect = TypeError() # doesn't work
    attrs = { 'attribute.method.side_effect': TypeError }
    library_client_mock.configure_mock(**attrs) # doesn't work

    with pytest.raises(TypeError):   
        using_library() # fails assertion
```

what I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Niel Godfrey Ponciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11043825/niel-godfrey-ponciano) set me on the right path with this syntax for the `side_effect`

```
library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.method.side_effect = TypeError
```

but it wasn't enough.

In

```py
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def library_client_mock(mocker):
    import Test as TestLibrary

    return mocker.patch.object(TestLibrary, 'Library')
```

I had to add an extra mock:

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def library_client_mock(mocker):
    import Test as TestLibrary

    mock_library_client = mocker.patch.object(TestLibrary, 'Library')
    # option 1
    mock_attribute = Mock()
    # option 2, path to Library.attribute = Attribute()
    mock_attribute = mocker.patch.object(TestLibrary.services, 'Attribute', autospec=True)
    mock_library_client.attach_mock(mock_attribute, "attribute")
    return mock_library_client
```

and then both of the following statements worked as expected. Although I am not sure why `return_value` works out of the box without an attached mock, but `side_effect` does not.

```
# return_value set correctly
# NOTE return_value needed after each
library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.return_value = "test"

# side_effect set correctly
# NOTE return_value not needed after "attribute"
library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.method.side_effect = TypeError
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the errors in your code:

1. Change:

   ```
   library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.return_value = "test"
   ```

   To:

   ```
   library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.method.return_value = "test"
   ```
2. Change:

   ```
   library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.side_effect = TypeError
   ```

   To:

   ```
   library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.method.side_effect = TypeError
   ```

#### Explanation

The `.return_value` must only be used for callable objects e.g. a function as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value):

> **`return_value`**
>
> Set this to configure the value returned **by calling the mock**:
>
> ```py
> >>> mock = Mock()
> >>> mock.return_value = 'fish'
> >>> mock()
> 'fish'
> ```

Thus, you can use `.return_value` only for the following:

- `TestLibrary.Library()`
- `TestLibrary.Library().attribute.method()`

But not for:

- `TestLibrary.Library().attribute`

Because `.attribute` is not a callable e.g. `TestLibrary.Library().attribute()`.

#### Warning

The way you are patching `Library` is via its source location at `Test.Library` (or aliased as `TestLibrary.Library`). specifically via:

```
import Test as TestLibrary
return mocker.patch.object(TestLibrary, 'Library')
```

It works currently because the way you import and use it is via the root path.

```
# client.py
import Test as TestLibrary
...
    return TestLibrary.Library()
...
```

But if we change the way we imported that library and imported a local version to **client.py**:

```
# client.py
from Test import Library  # Instead of <import Test as TestLibrary>
...
    return Library()  # Instead of <TestLibrary.Library()>
...
```

It will now fail. Ideally, you should [patch the specific name that is used by the system under test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), which here is `client.Library`.

```
import client
return mocker.patch.object(client, 'Library')
```

Unless you are sure that all files that will use the library will import only the root and not a local version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately your answer wasn't the final solution but it did help me get down the right path. I'll go into detail on the solution in a separate answer.
For the first (1) error you mention, what I wrote in my initial question was working correctly: `library_client_mock.return_value.attribute.return_value.method.return_value = "test"`, requiring the `return_value` call each time.
Regarding your warning, makes sense - however the Library doc does recommend the pattern `import Test` and then instantiation as `Test.Test()`.

Comment: Perhaps you can double check as probably `attribute` was called with `attribute()` or perhaps there was some left code in `using_library` the returns `"test"`. Anyways glad it helped a bit. An upvote wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: Done, thanks again. I think it probably had to do with the library_instance.attribute being set as Attribute(), but I am not clear on the exact mechanics behind why. See my question edit and my answer.